# Difference between async(req,res,next) and async(req,res,()=>{}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I recently came across this code and I fail to understand why the `next` has been omitted from the `protect` function(inside `protectandauth` function) while it is included in the `protect` function originally.
I want to know the difference between `protect=async(req,res,next)`and `protect=async(req,res,()=>{}`.

I also see that even though `next` is omitted in the `protect`(the one inside `protectandauth`) function, it is still used in the code after the 'if' statement, how is that possible?

Code:

```
export const protect = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")
  ) {
    let token;
    token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "kris");

    req.userId = decoded.id;

    try {
      req.user = await User.findById(req.userId).select("-password");

      next();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(401).json(error.message);
    }
    if (!token) {
      res.status(404).json("no token found");
    }
  }
};

export const protectandauth = async (req, res, next) => {
  protect(req, res, () => {
    if (req.userId == req.params.id) {
      next();
    } else {
      res.status(401).json("not authorised");
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Are you asking about the definition of `protect` or about the call to `protect`? It's really just passing the arrow function as the `next` parameter.

Comment: "*how is that possible?*" - notice there are two different `next` variables, declared as parameters of the different functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every callback where you access `req` and `res`, you can also access `next`. [`next`](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) is a function that's used to to say "pass to the next callback", knowing that a request can be processed by multiple callbacks, like so:

```js
const firstCallback= (req, res, next) => {}
const secondCallback= (req, res, next) => {}
app.get("/", firstCallback);
app.get("/", secondCallback);
```

```js
// or using this syntax
app.get("/", firstCallback, secondCallback);
```

In the above example, when a request comes to `/`, it's handled first by `firstCallback`, and it's one of the two below scenarios (otherwise the request will hang, and the user won't get a response):

1. It stops the request by calling one of the `res` methods, like `res.status(401).json("not authorised");`
2. It says "pass to the next callback" calling `next()`, and then `secondCallback` handles it.

If `next` is omitted from the parameters, you will be calling `next()` where it's `undefined`, and that throws an error. Speaking of the use of `protect` function, if you notice, there is `next` as part of `protectandauth`'s parameters, and it's that `next` that's used inside `protect`'s third parameter, which is:

```
 () => {
    if (req.userId == req.params.id) {
      next();
    } else {
      res.status(401).json("not authorised");
    }
  }
```

And in this specific code you have, the above function is passed as `next` in `protect`'s definition.

Comment: Thank you for taking time and explaining but I'm still confused between protect(req,res, next) and protect(req,res, ()=>{} . The first one has "next" explicitly mentioned as such it'll goto next middleware, the second instance doesn't have a next rather has a function.

Comment: I edited my answer, is it any better @KrishnaBharadwaj?

Comment: Okay so what if I do protect(req,res,next)=>{} instead of protect(req,res,()=>{}? Are both one and the same?The next which appears after if condition and the next of protect() function are same? Is that what you mean? Perhpas its silly, but I don't quite understand it properly.

Comment: Starting from this line `export const protect = async (req, res, next) => {`, you are defining `protect`, and you are saying what gets passed as third parameter will be called `next`. Then in `protectedandauth`, you are calling `protect` and giving it, `req`, `res` (from `protectedandauth`'s parameter), and a function that uses `next` (also  from `protectedandauth`'s parameter).

Comment: It's how your code is designed that's creating the confusion, as normally, `next` gets passed by Express as well as `req` and `res`, and you decided in `protectdandauth` to pass a custom function to `protect` where you expect `next`. And that custom function uses `next` that's  passed by Express to `protectdandauth`.

Comment: Okay, I guess, I understand now . What you're saying is that I'm calling protect function and then passing the req, res of protectandauth function as parameters right? I always saw protect as a separate function with separate req,res,next. If I understand correctly, the protect function merely is getting the req,res of protectandauth and then moving forward with next which is also of protectandauth. I guess I understand now. Thanks a tonn.

Comment: Yeah that's what's happening. Glad I could help @KrishnaBharadwaj :)

Answer (score 0):

We use next if we want to pass our request to the next middleware in line. Maybe in protect, the programmer might not want to pass the req to the next middleware but in protectandauth he want to pass the req to the next middleware if this condition turns out to be true

```
if (req.userId == req.params.id) {
      next();
}
```